# Dialog Window inside a Table and a Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I would like to make a dialog window that "pops up" when one clicks on a button. Currently, this exists as a modal popup window, which deemed inefficient since this does not work in Chrome (modal windows became deprecated).

These buttons occur multiple times as they sit in a loop, and subsequently, each entry would receive a button that each leads to another view, and that displays different content depending on the ID sent in.

Here is my current code for a modal popup window:

```
<table>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button"
                       name="Details"
                       value="@Model[i].SomeEntryID"
                       class="btn-bold btn-default"
                       onclick="javascript:window.showModalDialog('/Default/Selected/?id='+@Model[i].SomeEntryID)" />
            </td>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => Model[i], "lineEditorTemplate")
        </tr>
        }
        </table>
```

Is there a way to convert it to a dialog window? I can't seem to get dialogs to work inside a table/loop.

I am a newbie to Javascript and MVC too, so please bear with me with simple questions.

Thanks!

Comment: jquery ui has dialog() and bootstrap has modal().. i'd give those a shot

Comment: There are plenty of plugins for this, or you can create your own with a bit of css and jquery (refer [this simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/9madrh7g/2/))